# What is the meaning of "service done to"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

> And although the contribution is small, the river is
> great: After ages of **good service done to** those who people its banks, as
> Joseph Conrad said of the Thames, it spreads out "in the tranquil dignity of a
> waterway leading to the uttermost ends of the earth."

Does it mean that such service is done by those who people its banks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It means that the river has done good service to the people who live on the river's banks.

The grammar alone is not enough to make this clear. You have to understand that the only possible agent for the verb **done*** is the river.

Here is a similar sentence, which might be easier to understand:

> After years of **saving money**, the Smiths could afford to buy a house.

Who saved the money? The Smiths. The grammar doesn't say that the Smiths saved the money, but this is the only reasonable interpretation of the sentence.

---

* <sub>Strictly speaking, **done** is a past participle, which is a verbal adjective.</sub>